# How to override CSS with default configurations?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

In one file called first.css, there is a lot of CSS that I need in it but this is one piece of CSS that I don't need as seen here but seems to be getting applied to my `input`:

first.css:

```
.ng-invalid :not(.ng-valid)>.form-control {
  border-color: #b94a48;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
}

.ng-invalid :not(.ng-valid)>.form-control:focus {
  border-color: #953b39;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 6px #d59392;
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 6px #d59392;
}
```

I basically do not want that CSS not to apply to my input form so I do something like this:

second.css:

```
.ng-invalid :not(.ng-valid)>.form-control input {
  //I simply want the default CSS to apply, and not that from first.css
}

.ng-invalid :not(.ng-valid)>.form-control:focus input {
      //I simply want the default CSS to apply, and not that from first.css
}
```

second.html:

```
    <form style="margin-top: 10px" name="configurationForm" ng-class="{'submitted': submitted}" ng-submit="createConfiguration(configurationForm.$valid)" novalidate>
        <div class="form-group row" ng-class="{'has-error': configurationForm.name.$invalid && !configurationForm.name.$pristine && submitted }">
            <label for="name" class="col-xs-1 col-form-label">Name</label>
            <div class="col-xs-11">
                <input name="name" style="font-size: 10px; border-radius: 4px !important;" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" ng-model="configuration.name" required />
            </div>
        </div>
      ... <More form-control> ...
    </form>
```

Is there a way to simply prevent the CSS from first.css from applying? I simply want the default configurations (whatever they are) to apply and not the above which is why I left `second.css` css elements empty. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Try using '!important' keyword: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/

Comment: Important shouldn't be neccesary if you're including second after first.

Comment: @Nestoraj are you saying just include !important in the second.css CSS values?

Answer (score 2):

Load second.css after first.css

```
<head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="first.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="second.css">
</head>
```

Then in second css reset those style to `none` . But it seems like border-color can't have `none` value so you may try `transparent`

```
.ng-invalid :not(.ng-valid)>.form-control input {
  border-color: 'transparent';
  -webkit-box-shadow: 'none';
          box-shadow: 'none';

}

.ng-invalid :not(.ng-valid)>.form-control:focus input {
      border-color: 'transparent';
  -webkit-box-shadow: 'none';
          box-shadow: 'none'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use `none` value for `box-shadow` property in `second.css`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13743082)

Comment: @Jost This **is an answer**. Please go through and read [this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue) and [this post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) which specifies which answer should we delete in the LQP review queue, what we should just downvote and what we should just let remain.

Answer (score 0):

Just add new properties to `second.css` to override CSS style of `first.css`
https://jsfiddle.net/vLhuowss/

```css
.myDiv {
 height: 100px;
 width: 100px;
 background-color: red;
}

.myDiv {
 background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="myDiv"></div>
```